# How can i call the class method in python?

Tags: python

I created a class called LinkedList and a method inside this class called find().

I'm trying to call this method inside a function but it always return the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 44, in <module>
    BinaryInsertionSort(l.head, l.length())
  File "main.py", line 26, in BinaryInsertionSort
    item = list.find(i).data
AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I have another class called Node, but I don't think this would influence anything.

Please, someone help me! I don't know what is wrong....

Here is the link for the entire code: https://repl.it/@Mimik1/InsertionSortWithLinkedList#main.py

It's for a university project so I can't change the Binary Insertion sort at all, but if it is wrong, please tell me.

Comment: Try `BinaryInsertionSort(l, l.length())`

Comment: Also, it is a good idea not to overwrite built-in Python functions/keywords, such as `list` (although it sounds like you didn't write that part of the code). This will eventually cause problems, or at the very least, confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LinkedList.py in method add you assign a Node object to the member head. Which is later given to `BinaryInsertionSort` which expects an Object of type LinkedList not Node. So the problem is the call  `BinaryInsertionSort(l.head, l.length())` in main.py line 44. The call to the class method by `item = list.find(i).data` is alright.

Comment: I changed the call to BinaryInsertionSort(l, l.length()) as Justin Ezequiel said, but somehow it returned 4 5 3 3 3 3 2 1

Comment: Well, I guess that means the algorithm does not work properly. If You have a specific question with minimal example, you can create another question. This question was answered. You can accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your class structure states that a linked list holds a chain of nodes. Therefore, when you call `l.head` you return a `Node` and not another `LinkedList` which is why you are running into the error. A `Node` does not have the operations that a `LinkedList` has. You could design your `LinkedList` in such a way that it is comprised of itself at each link in the chain rather than comprised of `Node`s which would alleviate this issue.

Some other comments outside of the scope of the question:

I noticed that you set some integer type arguments to `None` as default. Generally, it would seem to be better to set them to a default integer (like 0 in main.py line 23).

I would also look at your logic for adding a node because intuitively it seems like the head should not change as I add more nodes. The head of the list is unchanging whereas I would assume the tail of the list is always the last node.